# Switching between apps in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I am making an app that needs to be able to switch between apps that the user has open (eg, the apps in the multitasking menu) I have got the `ComponentName` of the 10 most recent apps, and can launch them (ie, switch to them) like this:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setComponent(info);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, when I try and change to Facebook (And probably some similar apps) it requests a specific permission:

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.facebook.katana/.activity.FbFragmentChromeActivity } from ProcessRecord{42310bc0 8578:com.javanut13.multitaskheads/u0a10095} (pid=8578, uid=10095) requires **com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION**

Is there a way around this by actually switching to the app, rather than launching it? Can I simply send focus to a different app?

Comment: Try using this flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a permission, I think you can only launch other application's activity when its "exported" attribute is set to true. Facebook-like app might set this to false and does not allow other app's access to its activity.

I have not tested this by myself, but you can try following codes:

```
Intent extApp= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(facebook-package-name);
this.startActivity(extApp);
```

Hope this helps.

Reference:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)